# Ambiguous class resolution in laravel phpexcel update

Tags: php, excel, laravel, composer-php, laravel-excel

I try to update the laravel with php excel while installing i found the below warning in the composer.

**Error:**

```
Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "SettingsController" was found in both 

"C:\xampp\htdocs\mti\app\controllers\SettingsController.php" and 

"C:\xampp\htdocs\mti\app\controllers\SettingsControllerBackup.php", the first 

will be used.Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "ClassModel" was found in both

"C:\xampp\htdocs\mti\app\models\ClassModel.php" and "C:\xampp\htdocs\mti\

app\models\LoginModel.php", the first will be used.
```

**SettingsController:**

```
<?php

class SettingsController extends BaseController
{

    public function ChangePasswordLayout()
    {
        return View::make('settings/changepassword/changepassword');
    }

    public function ChangePasswordProcess()
    {
        $PasswordData = Input::all();

        Validator::extend('pwdvalidation', function($field, $value, $parameters)
        {
            return Hash::check($value, Auth::user()->password);
        });

        $messages = array('pwdvalidation' => 'The Old Password is Incorrect');

        $validator = Validator::make($PasswordData, User::$rulespwd, $messages);
        if ($validator->passes()) 
        {
            $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
            $user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('NewPassword'));
            $user->save();
            return Redirect::to('changepassword')->withInput()->with('Messages', 'The Password Information was Updated');
        } else 
        {
            return Redirect::to('changepassword')->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
        }

    }

    public function ProfileLayout()
    {
        $user = Auth::user()->id;
        $ProfileDetailsbyid = ProfileModel::where('id', $user)->get()->toArray();   
        return View::make('settings/profile/profile')->with('ProfileDetailsbyid', $ProfileDetailsbyid);
    }

    public function ProfileUpdateProcess($data=NULL)
    {

    $user = Auth::user()->id;
    $ProfileDetailsbyid = ProfileModel::where('id', $user)->get()->toArray();

        $ProfileData = array_filter(Input::except(array('_token')));

      $validation  = Validator::make($ProfileData, ProfileModel::$rules);        
        if ($validation->passes()) 
        {

        if(!empty($ProfileData['Photo']))
    {
    Input::file('Photo')->move('assets/uploads/profilephoto/', $user . '-Photo.' . Input::file('Photo')->getClientOriginalName());
    $Photo=$user.'-Photo.' . Input::file('Photo')->getClientOriginalName();
    unset($ProfileData['Photo']);
    $ProfileData['Photo']=$Photo;
    }

           $affectedRows = ProfileModel::where('id', $user)->update($ProfileData);
            //VehicleModel::create($VehicleData);
            return Redirect::to('profile')->with('Message', 'Profile Details Update Succesfully')->with('ProfileDetailsbyid', $ProfileDetailsbyid);
        } else 
        {

            return Redirect::to('profile')->withInput()->withErrors($validation->messages())->with('ProfileDetailsbyid', $ProfileDetailsbyid);
        }
    }


}
```

**ClassModel:**

```
<?php
class ClassModel extends Eloquent
{

    protected $primaryKey = 'AutoID';
    protected $created_at = 'CreatedAt';
    protected $updated_at = 'UpdatedAt';
    protected $table = 'class';
    protected $guarded = array('GradeName');
    protected $fillable = array('GradeName');

    public function batch(){
        return $this->hasMany('BatchModel', 'Class');
    }

    public function studentadmissionresult(){
        return $this->hasMany('StudentAdmissionModel', 'StudentCourse');
    }

    public $timestamps = true;



    public static $rules = array(
        'GradeName' =>  array('required', 'unique:class','regex:/^./'),
        'GradeSection' => 'required',
        'GradeCode' => array('required', 'unique:class')
                             );
     public static $updaterules = array(
        'GradeName' =>  array('required','regex:/^./'),
        'GradeSection' => 'required',
        'GradeCode' => array('required')
                             );                      

}
```

**I following this  tutorial:**

https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel

**I have try following command :**

```
composer require maatwebsite/excel": "~1.2.1
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This actually has nothing to do with the package you are installing.

### Explanation

When recreating the autoload files (`composer dump-autoload`) after the update Composer detected that you have two classes with the exact same name (but in different files).

Class `SettingsController` in `SettingsController.php` and `SettingsControllerBackup.php`

and class `ClassModel` in `ClassModel.php` and `LoginModel.php`

Composer will then choose to use one of the two (I'm not sure how it makes that decision, it's probably just the first one it finds) and will ignore the other occurrence. - [Confirmed. Composer uses first match](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/5849#issuecomment-258773958).

### Solutions

1. Delete the files if you don't need them
2. Rename the class

A good and common practice is to name the class like the file. This is a simple way to avoid such collisions because two files in the same directory can't have the same name.

Comment: I have this problem when using a symlink for my vendor directory. Is there any way to exclude directories for vendor to look at?

Comment: Sorry I don't do much PHP development anymore. Please ask a new question and I'm sure somebody else will be able to help you out.