# composer dump-autoload doesn´t work Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

If I run the `composer dump-autoload` in command line following happens :

```
Generating autoload files
Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "CreateRevisionsTable" was found in both "$baseDir . '/app/database/migrations/2013_04_09_062329_create_revisions‌​_table.php" and "C:\Users\Username\PhpstormProjects\projectname\www\ve ndor/venturecraft/revisionable/src/migrations\2013_04_09_062‌​329_create_revisions‌​_table.php" the first will be used
```

But then nothing happenes and if i want to go and check out my project in browser he can´t find the Classes.

The `autoload_classmap` seems to be correct, too but still the error.

I tried to fix it for half a week and don´t seem to get a solution.

Please help.

Edit : Pasted in the file directorys 
Additional Note : This error only happens to me. Other people working on this repository( shared via git) are totally fine

I recently upgraded my xampp to the php 7 version but even if i downgrade again it won´t work...

Answer (score 1):

Ok i solved it... had to put the short_open_tag=On in my php.ini file... such a dumb little thing..

Answer (score 0):

What is the bla bla bit as this tells you where its being duplicated. You need to either rename one or see why it thinks you have two the same name.
Also does this help?
[suppress-ambiguous-class-resolution-warning-on-composer-dump-autoload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23316761/suppress-ambiguous-class-resolution-warning-on-composer-dump-autoload-o)

or

[ambiguous-class-resolution-in-laravel-phpexcel-update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27936911/ambiguous-class-resolution-in-laravel-phpexcel-update)

Comment: Unfortunately not... i even tried to delete one of the two but nothing changed. he then just left the part out where he says the file locations

These are 
"$baseDir . '/app/database/migrations/2013_04_09_062329_create_revisions_table.php" and "C:\Users\Username\PhpstormProjects\projectname\www\ve
ndor/venturecraft/revisionable/src/migrations\2013_04_09_062329_create_revisions_table.php"

Comment: Can you edit your answer and replace the bla bla. It with the actual error please.